# Is there an idiom that means that someone has a compromising information on you?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means that someone has a compromising information on you? I was watching a video on Russian alleged possession of a pee tape against Trump and was wondering if there's an idiom that means someone has a compromising material on someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one that comes to mind is to **have dirt** on someone

[evidence](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/dirt)  See definition 4.